# JSon Retrofit Mal Formado

Tags: android, retrofit

Estou com meu retorno em json assim:

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "email": "meuemail@gmail.com"
}
```

Mas o retrofit está dizendo que está mal formado:

Dá a seguinte mensagem:

> use JsonReader.setLenien(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1
>   column 1 path $

Minha classe de mensagem está assim:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class RetornoMensagem {


    @SerializedName("success")

    private Integer success;
    @SerializedName("email")

    private String email;

    public Integer getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(Integer success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

Gostaria de ver como está retornando no retrofit também no Throwable t

Comment: Você gostaria de saber como está retornando? como faz para ver o retorno na aplicação?

Comment: Decobri. Era erro meu. Eu nao estava enviando todos os parametros